# onCreateOptionsMenu not called on tab swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

action bar menu not changed,

`onCreateOptionsMenu` not called on swipe, or on tab cange

i have 3 tabs,
in each tab i manage stackfragements,

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TabA").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_feed)),ATabFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TabB").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_explor)),BTabFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TabC").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_favorit)),CTabFragment.class, null);
```

each tab inflate a uniq xml like

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/A_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

and in the fragment i create the first stacked item,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.A_tab_fragemt_stack,
            container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
        Fragment newFragment = AFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.A_container, newFragment).commit();
    }

    return view;

}
```

Comment: are you calling invalidateOptionsMenu()?

Comment: yes and no, when i did it cased all tabs to call onCreateOptionsMenu. for now i added a bad fix, i manage setHasOptionsMenu (mode) for all tabs in onPageSelcted event at the adupter, it wrong, but it work, still wait for better solution